# Simple not-authorized request to a Github API using Tornado httpclient returns Forbidden

Tags: python, http, tornado

I am trying to make a HTTP Request to a JSON API like `https://api.github.com` using `tornado.httpclient` and I found that it always responses with FORBIDDEN 403.

Simplifying, I make a request using the CLI with:

`$ python -m tornado.httpclient https://api.github.com`

getting a `tornado.httpclient.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden`.

In other hand, if I try to request this URL via browser or a simple `$ curl https://api.github.com`, the response is 200 OK and the proper JSON file.

What is causing this? Should I set some specific Headers on the `tornado.httpclient` request? What's the difference with a `curl` request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put user agent in the request, see [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required) for more details:

> All API requests MUST include a valid `User-Agent` header. Requests with
>   no `User-Agent` header will be rejected. We request that you use your
>   GitHub username, or the name of your application, for the `User-Agent`
>   header value. This allows us to contact you if there are problems

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with their [robots.txt](https://api.github.com/robots.txt).  Maybe tornado.httpclient modifies the User-Agent in a way that makes it appear to be a web crawler?  I'm not that familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue & problem was with `configurable-http-proxy` so I killed its process & restarted `jupyterhub`

`ps aux | grep configurable-http-proxy`

if there are any pid's from above command, kill them with

`kill -9 <PID>`

and restart ``